# What does this mean in gdb?

Tags: c, debugging, gcc, gdb

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x08049795 in execute_jobs ()
Current language:  auto; currently asm

(gdb) info symbol 0x08049795
execute_jobs + 22 in section .text

(gdb) ptype 0x08049795
type = int

How to get the line number at which the error occurred?

Comment: First, you'll want to compile with -ggdb3, then GDB will give you that info.

Comment: Compile with debugging symbols and no optimization then run it through valgrind. You will immediately see the cause of the segfault, just by watching the fireworks :) See http://valgrind.org

Answer (score 7):

Your binary was not compiled with debugging information. Rebuild with at least `-g` (or `-ggdb`, or `-ggdb -g3`, see [GCC manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.0/gcc/).)

The exact lines from GDB output:

```
(gdb) info symbol 0x08049795 execute_jobs + 22 in section .text
```

means that instruction at address `0x08049795`, which is 22 bytes from beginning of function `execute_jobs`, generated the segmentation fault.

```
(gdb) ptype 0x08049795 type = int
```

Here you are asking for type of an integer, and GDB happily replies. Do

```
(gdb) x/10i 0x08049795
```

or

```
(gdb) disassemble execute_jobs
```

to see actual instructions.

Comment: Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0804ae71 in job_comparator_randomjobid (element1=0x804d0c0, element2=0x804d354) at ./machinejob.c:860

860   JOB job1 = *((JOB*) element1);

How to determine the exact error that caused segmentation fault?

Comment: @blacktooth, you have to show code from `machinejob.c` around line 860 for us to be able to help you. `JOB` is what? A pointer? What's the type of `element1`? The root cause is an invalid address somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

The gdb command "bt" will show you a back trace. Unless you've corrupted the stack this should show the sequence of function calls that lead to the segfault. To get more meaningful information make sure that you've compiled your program with debug information by including -g on the gcc/g++ command line.

Comment: Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0804ae2a in job_comparator_randomjobid (element1=0x804d0c0, element2=0x804d60c) at ./machinejob.c:860
860   JOB job1 = *((JOB*) element1);
(gdb) info symbol 0x0804ae2a
job_comparator_randomjobid + 20 in section .text



What's 20 above?